# jQuery: trying hook a function to the onclick when dynamically adding a DOM element, but it immediately executes the function instead

Tags: jquery, onclick

I am using jQuery to dynamically (I mean at runtime) add a span element to my page's DOM:

```
// create add task button
$(document.createElement("span"))
    .attr({ id: activityNameHyphened + "-NewButton", name: activityNameHyphened + "-NewButton" })
    .addClass("smallButton")
    .appendTo(cell1)
    .click(CreateTaskRow(ActivityName));
```

The problem is the last line: I thought it would add CreateTaskRow(ActivityName) as the handler for the onclick event of the span, just like:

```
<span onclick="CreateTaskRow(ActivityName);"></span>
```

which is what I want - but when I run it in the browser, I can see using the debugger that at this line it *immediately runs the function* instead.

If I can make it clearer: CreateTaskRow() runs when I'm trying to add it to the onclick (I want it to run only when the user actually clicks the span).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? (and please let me know if my question isn't clear enough)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are actually calling the function and passing the result to the `.click()` event handler. Try it with a closure (anonymous function) instead:

```
.click(function() {
    CreateTaskRow(ActivityName);
});
```

The closure will not be run until the `click` event is fired.

Answer (score 2):

Try with a closure

```
$("<span>")
    .attr({ id: activityNameHyphened + "-NewButton", name: activityNameHyphened + "-NewButton" })
    .addClass("smallButton")
    .appendTo(cell1)
    .click(function() { CreateTaskRow(ActivityName); });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/abasi)**

Code from the demo -

```
$(function() {

  var activityNameHyphened = "id1";
  var ActivityName = "This is the highlighted activity";

  $('#clickMe').click(function() {

    $("<span>I've been added</span>")
        .attr({ id: activityNameHyphened + "-NewButton", 
              name: activityNameHyphened + "-NewButton" 
            })
        .addClass("smallButton")
        .appendTo("#here")
        .click(function() { CreateTaskRow(ActivityName); });        
  });    
});


function CreateTaskRow(e)
{
  alert(e);
}
```

Comment: Awesome, a demo and everything. The accepted answer was more concise, but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can define an event handler for elements you create before creating them using `live()` method.

```
$("span.smallButton").live("click", function () {
    CreateTaskRow(ActivityName);
});
```

Then when you create new element, you don't have to remember about hooking events to it.

```
$(document.createElement("span"))
    .attr({ id: activityNameHyphened + "-NewButton", name: activityNameHyphened + "-NewButton" })
    .addClass("smallButton")
    .appendTo(cell1);
```

Comment: Interesting, I may use this later.

Answer (score 0):

.click triggers the click event, you must bind the function to the click event:

```
$("p").bind("click", function(e) {
      var str = "( " + e.pageX + ", " + e.pageY + " )";
      $("span").text("Click happened! " + str);
});
```